# How to collapse AppBarLayout at start?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some AppBarLayout which I need to collapse at start the application.

I already tried to apply `appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);`but it behaves very strangely. [gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u46nN.gif)

It looks expanded, but at the same time behaves as collapsed. So I'm looking for another way.

Thank you. Have a nice day.

Comment: you want to remove it?

Comment: @peco, I want to collapse it as default.